# JavaScript & PHP replace string containing X and reuse the strings before and after X

Tags: javascript, php

I have a custom way of adding links in a message, the text would look something like this:

```
<?php
    $message = 'Some text some text mylink@https://www.mylink.com some text some text some text';
?>
```

I want to get all occurances of the pattern `somelink@linkurl` and replace them with

```
<a href='linkurl'>somelink</a>
```

as to make a real link of it once the user submits his message.

I need to do this both in JavaScript and PHP. I actually had already an idea how to do it and it would involve splitting the string by a delimiter, then filtering all by searching for `@`-signs and then somehow put everything together after I replace the corresponding values.

My idea sounds very complicated so I was hoping there is a simpler more efficient way to achieve the same result.

How would I best do this in both in Javascript and PHP?

Comment: You can simply use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) on the js side and [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the PHP side.

Comment: Why JS _and_ PHP? If you replace it using JS there's no need to replace anything in PHP

Comment: And how do you write an email address with your "custom way"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the hint, didn't think about that. I'm just going to use another symbol instead.

Comment: @brombeer PHP is used when loading the page (data from sever) and JavaScript is used to dynamically update the message box on the page, (data from server through XMLHttp). This means the same string goes directly through PHP in the first case and in the second case it goes to the JavaScript callback. It's just how I've set everything up.

Comment: @brombeer by the way If you do not approve of a "custom way", is there a better solution I should use? I use a "custom way" because I couldn't use HTML-Tags here, it could potentially be too complicated for the user

Comment: I don't have enough info and I'm not the one to approve anything on your end, it's your site. ;) Your comment mentions "_data from sever_" twice, so it would suffice to just replace it in PHP. After all, there wouldn't be anything to replace in JS. Depending on what "features" you want in your messages, have you considered using Markdown as used here on the site? Links would be `[ mylink ]( https://www.mylink.com )` (without the spaces) and your users would also have the ability to make text **bold** or _italic_ etc.

Comment: @brombeer thanks for the reply. Yes I figured PHP would be enough, I'll probably change that later when I do a thorough clean up. And about the Markup, would it be easier to implement those? I would still end up with the same problem as I do now, right? I'd still have to replace all occurrences of markdown and replace them with the corresponding HTML-Tags, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You'd still have to parse, yes. But there are some solid libraries out there like ParseDown or CommonMark

Comment: @brombeer I see, well thanks, I'll look into it but for now, I prefer my way. It's just a too small part of my website to justify including a whole markup library just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same regex pattern in both languages:

```
/([^ ]+)@([^ ]+)/
```

*`([^ ]+)` means "anything except for space", so it also includes underscore and other characters that can be in URL but are not in the `\w` regex symbol for word character.*

and replace it with

```
<a href='$2'>$1</a>
```

---

PHP:

```
<?php
$re = '/([^ ]+)@([^ ]+)/';
$str = 'Some text some text mylink@https://www.mylink.com some text some text some text';
$subst = '<a href=\'$2\'>$1</a>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

---

JS:

```
const regex = /([^ ]+)@([^ ]+)/;
const str = `Some text some text mylink@https://www.mylink.com some text some text some text`;
const subst = `<a href='$2'>$1</a>`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
```

---

Result:

```
Some text some text <a href='https://www.mylink.com'>mylink</a> some text some text some text
```